# How switching from HTTP(RESTful) to TCP socket with WSO2 ESB/EI

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I've got a service A which is a RESTful client and can send requests periodically, and another service B which is a TCP socket server and can receive tcp socket message. So, my question is whether there's solution to transfer the message from A to B, viz, switching message from http to tcp socket with WSO2 ESB/EI. Actually, I found a guide about [how switching from TCP to HTTP/S](https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=33136069) but not from http to tcp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following proxy will work, provided the tcp sender is configured in axis configuration as specified [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Setting+Up+the+ESB+Samples#SettingUptheESBSamples-ConfiguringWSO2ESBtousetheTCPtransport)

```
<proxy name="TestProxy" transports="http">
        <target>
            <endpoint>
                <address uri="tcp://localhost:6060/TestService"/>
            </endpoint>
            <inSequence>
                <log level="full"/>
                <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
            </inSequence>
        </target>
    </proxy>
```

Comment: By the above proxy after sending message from http to tcp, is it possible to get messages without disconnecting after that(i mean does the above proxy disconnects after sending message or the connection will be held even after that ).

Comment: in the above case, it will disconnect as it is marked as OUT_ONLY