# Sending Data over TCP on wso2 ESB

Tags: tcp, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have created a code where an external system can call wso2 esb over TCP and pass data, this is working fine without any issues however the reverse process is not happening and i am getting confused.

Here i would need to pass certain data to external system over TCP, however i am unable to do so as the parameters which are available while developing proxy doesn't contain IP address, it just contain port number, so i am curious as to how can the communication even be established when the IP address is not mentioned in the proxy.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="TCPProxyClient"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="symbol" scope="default" type="STRING" value="IBM"/>
         <enrich>
            <source clone="true" type="inline">
               <m:getQuote xmlns:m="http://services.samples">
                  <m:request>
                     <m:symbol>?</m:symbol>
                  </m:request>
               </m:getQuote>
            </source>
            <target type="body"/>
         </enrich>
         <enrich>
            <source clone="true" property="symbol" type="property"/>
            <target xmlns:m="http://services.samples" xpath="//m:getQuote/m:request/m:symbol"/>
         </enrich>
         <log level="full" separator=","/>
         <send/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.tcp.responseClient">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.tcp.inputType">string</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.tcp.recordDelimiter">|</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.tcp.contentType">text/xml</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.tcp.port">8691</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.tcp.recordDelimiterType">character</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters above are used only when the proxy is listening for TCP messages. For sending a TCP message to a TCP socket, you need to define an endpoint in the send mediator.

```
<send>
   <endpoint>
     <address uri="tcp://localhost:8001/helloService"/>
   </endpoint>
<send>
```

Follow the doc [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/TCP+Transport) to enable to TCP transport sender in axis2.xml.
Refer the question [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312534/how-switching-from-httprestful-to-tcp-socket-with-wso2-esb-ei) for more info.

Comment: Thank you @thishani , i was able to call the server over TCP.